# cfscript language="javascript" does not work

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Here is my code:

```
<cfscript language="javascript">
      OpenText(document.getElementById(#url.id#));
</cfscript>
```

Here is the error:

```
Invalid token l found on line 731 at column 19.

The CFML compiler was processing:

A cfscript tag beginning on line 731, column 10.
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<cfscript>` doesn't take a *language* attribute.  You are probably just wanting to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<cfoutput>
OpenText(document.getElementById(#url.id#));
</cfoutput>
</script>
```

Incidentally, the *language* attribute is also deprecated on the `<script>` tag in HTML 4, and you should use *type* instead (as in my example).  In HTML5 you can just do `<script>` without either *language* or *type* attributes.

Comment: Dumping client-provided values direct to page enables JS injection - should be doing `document.getElementById('#JsStringFormat(url.id)#')` (or in CF10/equiv encodeForJavaScript).

Answer (score 4):

[OpenBD supports this apparently](http://openbd.org/manual/?/cfscript_javascript), but ColdFusion does not.